# .NET 8.0 - Simplest way to implement Blazor WebAssembly third party authentication that enables authenticating backend requests

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm using .NET 8.0 and I want to create a Blazor WebAssembly site. I want to have users authenticate by using third party auth sources, e.g. Google. I also want to be able to authenticate the API requests the WebAssembly code makes to my own backend.

I don't need to support my username&password auth, and I don't want to use Identity store where ASP.NET Identity would be storing the user accounts to an SQL database.

Documentation from Microsoft on the topic is slightly confusing. There is guidance about [using Authentication library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio). Also I tried creating a Blazor Web App from a VS template, and the template has a link to [external provider auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio) docs, which provides some different guidance.

The .NET 8 version of the Blazor Web App template is also a bit confusing. The template let's you choose different options for "interactive render mode". I chose "WebAssembly". What the template creates is a VS solution that has two project. I think the other one is basically a server-side ASP.NET project and the other one is the Blazor WebAssembly project. The "render mode" thing seems to be something new on .NET 8 Blazor. At some point I was thinking I'm working with a "Blazor WebAssembly" project, but maybe it's actually so that it's more like a Blazor Server project with Interactive WebAssembly render mode. Confusing.

After some tweaking I got Google auth working in my project, at least to some degree. I think the most important part of the settings is this part in the Program.cs of the server-side project:

```
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection =
                    builder.Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");
                options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
            });
```

In my solution I'm able to be redirected to Google's page for auth and the auth succeeds. I'm able to read claims from the token. However, the auth information only seems to be available on the WebAssembly side of the app. It's not available in the HttpContext when processing an API request on the backend. Also, in the WebAssembly side I can't figure out any way to access the actual token, so that I could pass the signed token to the backend API requests, and have a reasonable authentication for them also. I definitely need to have the API requests authenticated in some reliable way.

I don't insist on keeping the proto project I started. I'm willing to start fresh from some new VS Blazor template. So my question is what the title says: what is the simplest way to implement a Blazor WebAssembly app and use a third party auth source (e.g. Google) in such a way that enables you to also authenticate your requests to the backend?

Some options maybe to consider:

- Implement a real standalone Blazor WASM app. Implement the auth using some way that enables me to actually access the auth JWT token, and then pass that token also to backend requests, and have the backend validate the tokens.
- Implement this kind of .NET 8 Blazor app with render modes, maybe try to make it so that the actual login page is rendered on the server side, but the main parts of the app on the WebAssembly. This way I could register the auth on the server-side, and then somehow pass the auth back and forth between the APIs on the server and the WebAssembly side. Does this maybe sound like uncharted territory?
- Some other way?

**UPDATE:**
I made a fresh start with a Standalone Blazor WebAssembly template. I followed the [using Authentication library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio) instructions for setting up the auth. I can get the auth to work to some degree, but I still have similar problems:

- I'm not able to configure any arbitrary scope in `options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("{SCOPE URI}");` Whatever I try will make the sign-in fail with "invalid scope" error. Seems that the only allowed scopes would be URIs for Google's API. I can't define just some scope for my own application.
- I'm not able to get any access token, that I could then put into my API requests to my backend. I think this is related to not defining any scope.
- The Authentication library only seems to work with request_type of "id_token". If I change to request_type to "token" in the appsettings, then I can see that Google returns an actual JWT token, which probably would be something I like. But the Authentication library doesn't seem to like that, and the login just hangs. (I know Google is returning a JWT token by inspecting the network requests using Dev Tools in browser.)

Any ideas on how to continue? Basically what I would just need is:

- Implement client-side sign-in with Google.
- Get a JWT token back.
- Be able to inspect the claims in the JWT token (name, userid).
- Include the JWT token as a Bearer token when I make API requests to my own backend.
- Have some reasonable way for the backend to validate those JWT tokens and inspect the claims.

How difficult can that be?

**UPDATE 2:**
I've been banging my head on a wall for a couple of days and I have learned this:

- I can get Google to return some kind of "access token" if I use the response_type of "id_token token". However, the included access token is not actually a valid signed JWT token, but something malformed and invalid. You can access this as if it were an actual access token, but it will never pass any JWT validation. No idea why Google returns a token like this.
- However, I found a way to "grab" the working id token from the URL when Google makes the login callback request back to the Blazor app. I find it astounding that I can't access the actual token through any API. But if I grab it like this, I can manually include it in the backend requests and validate in the backend side quite easily.
- Screw Google for returning an invalid token.
- Screw Microsoft for API design and misleading documentation.

Let's see, once I get to clean this up a bit, I might make my solution available as some kind of project template. Let me know if you're interested...

Comment: I assuming that you are trying to have a single page application like what we could have with react/Vue/angular via Blazor web assemble. If so, then you should try to have a blazor web assembly stand alone application but not the latest Blazor web app. In .net 8 we have blazor web app to replace the blazor server, because we can use different render mode in it so that we can use server side render and client side render both in the same project and take the advantages of these 2 render mode. But you should create Blazor wsam instead of blazor web app. Then you need to integrate 3rd authenticat

Comment: 3rd authentication(sign in user) and authorization(generate access token after sign in) in your blazor wsam app, then use the token to call your secured backend API which should also integrating this 3rd authentication to validate the token

Comment: we can find [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/sample-v2-code?tabs=apptype#single-page-applications) for azure ad authentication which is also what you said 3rd library here, but it hasn't updated with .net 8 version, just for reference.

Comment: I'm currently hitting the same wall as you. I'm trying to integrate the jwt authentication used in my company into the new Blazor template (SSSR + WebAssembly). The problem I'm having is for WebAssembly pages with authorize attributes, I get the browser awful 401 error, instead of get redirected to the Login page in the server project.